# Configuration is null when I use Dependency Injection to read the app settings of my Azure Function

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.1

I wrote an Azure Function that connects to a CosmosDB database through a Gremlin Server instance. In order to create the Gremlin Server instance, I need a few credentials that I saved in `local.settings.json` to debug locally, and that I wanted to retrieve through dependency injection.

To do so, I have created a custom type called `CosmosDBCredentials`, I have added a Startup class to my function app, and I have added a constructor to my function.

Here is the code of my newly created Startup class :

```
namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddOptions<CosmosDBCredentials>()
                .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
                {
                    configuration.GetSection("CosmosDBCredentials").Bind(settings);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code of my function constructor that receives the options as parameters :

```
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly CosmosDBCredentials _cosmosDBsettings;

        public Function1(IOptions<CosmosDBCredentials> cosmosDBsettings)
        {
            this._cosmosDBsettings = cosmosDBsettings.Value;
        }
```

When I excecute my function locally, the Startup class throws the following exception when it tries to bind the settings :

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'
>
> configuration was null.

I am quite confused as to what might have caused this, since I have followed the Microsoft documentation on [how work with options and settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#working-with-options-and-settings) to the letter.

Any clue as to why the Startup class can't seem to resolve the IConfiguration ?

I a quite new to Dependency Injection in .NET Core projects and more specifically Azure Functions, please don't hesitate to correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Your code looks fine, have you ensured you're on the latest versions of the various Azure Functions NuGet packages? Some older versions have game-breaking bugs like this. Also, did you see the "Warning" at the bottom of the page you linked to? It may or my not apply to your instance (you don't specify whether you're debugging the function locally, or if this only happens when you push it to Azure...)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'm indeed debugging locally, I will edit my question to add this information, it's important indeed.

Comment: The version of the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` package I'm using is 1.0.31. I've done a little test project as suggested below, which uses version 3.0.3, and this it works fine. I'll try to update and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: So I've re-created another test project, using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version 1.0.31 (like my big project) and this one works fine as well. So I guess my issue is not related to my Azure Functions NuGet package. I am really at a loss, here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Ian Kemp, I finally found where my issue came from : I was using a version of the EPPlus NuGet package that was forcing `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` to update to a 3.x.x version, which is not compatible with Azure Functions v2. I reinstalled all my dependencies, and this time I selected an older version of the EPPlus NuGet package, which is dependent on the version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` that I need, and that solved the issue.